# Tem como usar dois tipos de métodos de pagamento em uma transação no mercadopago?

Tags: php, javascript, pagamento-online

Por exemplo quero vender um produto que inclua adesão e mensalidade, **R$X,XX + R$X,XX** debito automático.

Exemplo de debito automático:

```
$preapproval_data = array(
        "payer_email" => "teste@email.com",
        "back_url" => "http://www.google.com.br",
        "reason" => "TESTE",
        "external_reference" => "OP-1234",
        "auto_recurring" => array(
           "frequency" => 1,
           "frequency_type" => "months",
           "transaction_amount" => 0.5,
           "currency_id" => "BRL",
           "start_date" => "2016-09-20T20:58:11.778-03:00"
        )
);
$preference = $mp->create_preapproval_payment($preapproval_data);
```

**Exemplo de pagamento simples:**

```
$preference_data = array(
    "reason" => "Adesão",
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Adesão",
            "currency_id" => "BRL",
            "category_id" => "",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "unit_price" => 100
        )

    ),
    "payment_methods" => array(
    "installments" => 24
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```

Teria alguma maneira de criar uma transação que inclua os **dois métodos de pagamento**?

Comment: se Há uma maneira de fazer isso? Claro que sim. Mas duvido que alguem a vá fazer por ti sem tu teres mostrado que coisas já tentas-te..

Comment: Exato, de mão beijada vai ser difícil o pessoal ajudar. Posta ai o que vc já tentou que fica mais fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente a API atual do Mercado Livre ainda não permite múltiplas formas de pagamento por pedido, porém você pode gerenciar isso internamente, e se necessário criar duas transações para cada pedido (não recomendo se não for extremamente importante para o seu negócio, visto que você terá maior complexidade para gerenciar o faturamento, e poderá ter problemas com estorno quando algum dos cartões for recusado).

Se mesmo com as ressalvas acima for interessante pra você aplicar o conceito:

Altere sua tabela de pedidos adicionando duas colunas para guardar os `ids` das duas transações (**forma fácil**) ou modifique sua modelagem para suportar múltiplas formas de pagamento por pedido (**forma difícil, requer uma nova tabela contendo as formas de pagamento associadas ao pedido 1/N**), assim se o cliente optar por pagar com dois cartões, você conseguirá registrar os dados de ambos os pagamentos.

Atente para o fato de que se uma das transações for recusada, a outra deve ser estornada.

Comment: Então Felipe, acho que **"Não é possível"** é sempre uma resposta válida, e até mesmo um **"Não é recomendável"**, mas acho que, nestes casos, no mínimo é preciso explicar **porque** é impossível, ou não recomendado. Na verdade, neste caso acho que o ideal mesmo seria você demonstrar como criar internamente as duas transações para cada pedido, e durante esta demonstração, explicar porque não é recomendado.

Comment: @gustavox a dúvida dele é sobre a integração o formato de duas transações por pedido em geral exige adaptações no banco de dados vou seguir sua dica mais acho que isso foge o contesto

Comment: Legal Felipe, quanto mais você melhorar sua resposta, maior a chance dela ser bem recebida pela comunidade. Eu de você ainda colocaria algum código de exemplo, mesmo que seja apenas pra ilustrar um ponto.... De qualquer forma, você foi o único que se dispôs a fazer uma resposta, e merece pelo menos o meu +1. Valeu.

Comment: Fiz o processo em duas etapas mesmo, primeiro com o pagamento da adesão e em seguida fiz o processo de pagamento da assinatura... ate o momento esta funcional, agradeço pelas respostas de vcs.